# Rxjs Error handling when combining two observables (combineLatest, Zip)

Tags: system.reactive, rxjs, onerror

On one hand I have an http request result that can be observed in `httpRequest$`.
On an other hand, I have a loader creation that can be observed in `loader$`.

I want to launch the loader and the httpRequest at the same time, and **dispose the loader** when the httpRequest succeeded **or falls into error**.

I have t his piece of code which works great for successful requests:

```
return loader$.combineLatest(httpRequest$) // or zip...
            .map(_ => ({loader: _[0], response: _[1]}))
            .do(_ => _.loader.dispose())
            .map(_ => _.response)
            [...]
```

But when I have an error, I didn't find a way to recover my loader to dispose it.

Is there a way to make it with Rx?

Moreover, I don't want to create my loader appart from my Rx stream: If anyone subscribe the Rx stream, I don't want the loader to be created.

Thanks!

Comment: .NET Rx has a `Observable.Using` operator for creating and disposing of resources required to create a stream. Does RXJS? Also `combineLatest` and `zip` do similar, but different things - which did you want?

Comment: Thanks Enigmativity, I looked at the documentation and guess `using` operator is indeed exactly what I was looking for to dispose my loader. I'll try it and keep you informed.
For zip or combinelatest, as I have loader construction and httpRequest response to observe (thus, a pair of event), both operator have exactly the same effect. combineLatest seemed to me more suitable from a semantic point of view...

Comment: If you have two observables that produce two values each then `zip` will produce two values, but `combineLatest` will produce either two or three values, depending on the order that the sources produce them. If it produces two then they will be different from the two that `zip` produces.

Comment: The order the 2 items are popping is definitely crucial, thanks a lot for this!!
This promotes Zip as the operator I must use for this case (at least, not combineLast).